# Dexguard running during debug build in ant?

Tags: java, android, ant, proguard

This is actually a two-parter (let me know if I should split the question). I am using Intellij as an IDE. The build works completely fine if I run from that. When I use ant, however, things start to mess up.

In the process of writing an automated test for my app, I have discovered two things: First, dexguard runs when I `ant clean debug`. Second, when I do this, I get the following error, but the build completes "successfully":

> [dexguard] Unexpected error while converting: 
>   [dexguard] Class     = [com/framework/notification/NotificationDetailBuilder] 
>   [dexguard] Method    = [getScheduledNotificationDetail()Lcom/framework/base/notification/NotificationDetail;]
>   [dexguard] Exception = [java.lang.IllegalStateException] (Negative variable v-1 for instruction [iget v-1, v0, field_12165])
>   [dexguard]   at com.saikoa.dexguard.fS.b(dexGuard:1219)
>   etc. etc.

So first off, what dumb thing did I do to get dexguard to run during debug.
And Second, what in the world does this error even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the standard Android build process, ProGuard is only applied for release builds. DexGuard is integrated more tightly in the build process; it is applied for debug builds and for release builds. You can reach me at saikoa.com to investigate the message that you get. The first step will be to make sure that you are using the latest version of DexGuard.

(I am the developer of ProGuard and DexGuard)

Comment: Hi @Eric.I am using dexguard(com.saikoa.dexguard.eclipse.adt-22.0.0.v5_4_17).but it is not working

Comment: I simply copied this jar file and put it into dropins folder of my eclipse ,and comppile my project ,but it is not working

Comment: You should check the minimum version requirements for Eclipse and the Android plugin in the documentation. If you're exporting your app, you may need some additional configuration, just as with ProGuard. Contact me with details at saikoa.com, and we'll look into it.

Comment: Hi @Eric Lafortune.Please answer me on this link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755671/implementation-of-dexguard.