# Implementation of dexguard

Tags: android, dexguard

i have put com.saikoa.dexguard.eclipse.adt_*.jar file in dropin folders of eclipse.And modified the Proguard-Project and Project-Properties Files in android Project.And i build the release version of .apk.The thing my apk is obfustcated,shrinked.but i also want my assets to be obfuscated.This is not happening.So,how to obfuscate the assets of your android project with the help of dexguard.

Answer (score 2):

DexGuard provides the option `-encryptassetfiles` to encrypt assets. It is documented in the DexGuard manual > Settings > -encryptassetfiles. The samples directory also contains a sample project that illustrates the feature.

Comment: Hi @eric, i have followed every steps written in dexguard ->manual_>settings>encryptassetfiles . i have run the sample directory also in release mode but still the assets files inside the asset folder is not encrypted. I don't know why this is happening ,can u tell me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: In my assets folder , i have only one .txt files which contained the a single text

Comment: i can easily get the assets content using apk tool

Comment: @abh22ishek If you contact support, we'll work it out.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this same problem and found the solution in the docs.

> This means that your code must invoke the AsssetManager as follows:
>   open("MyAssetFile").

If you are not loading your asset in that manner then Dexguard does not encrypt the asset.

For example, you must open your asset like this:

```
InputStream stream = context.getAssets().open("myAssetFile.html");
```

rather than

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myAssetFile.html");
```

You also need to ensure that you have set your dexguard config to encrypt your assets:

```
-encryptassetfiles assets/myAssetFile.html,assets/myOtherAssetFile.txt
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the usage? With an example maybe. Thanks !